# How to create a multi row vertical slider?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I would like to create a slider with the framework Swiper like the homepage of this website: https://lindsayadlerphotography.com/

I tried several configurations like:
direction: "vertical",
slidesPerView: 4,
slidesPerColumn: 2,

this is the code I'm using actually:

```
  const swiperHomeSlider = new Swiper('.swiper-container-home', {
slidesPerView: 4,
direction: 'vertical',
autoHeight: true,
spaceBetween: 25,
freeMode: true,
loop: true,
speed: 5000,

autoplay: {
  delay: 0,
  disableOnInteraction: false,
},
```

});

but I'm not able to reach the desired result

Can anybody give a hand?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.